# How do I record a purchase of gas in a gnucash chart of accounts?

Tags: accounting, gnucash, cash

Complete beginner here.
Eyes sore and brain bent from reading.  My question too basic for anyone to answer it seems.
It is this:

I start off with the new chart of accounts.  I spend $50 on gas.  How do I enter that?

Credit cash with $50 ?
Debit the expense account 'auto/fuel' with $50?

Or do one of those and gnucash does the other?

Or what?

This the essence of the whole thing, I think, but not spelled out that i could find.

:)

Answer (score 8):

As for recording this in a double-entry accounting system, you're absolutely on the right track.  You need to credit the source of funds (your *Cash* account in this case) with $50, and debit the destination account (*Expenses:auto:fuel*) with the same amount.  If you also bought a chocolate bar at the service station, you can use **transaction splits** to show that the $50 was spent partly on *Expenses:auto:fuel* and partly on *Expenses:snacks*.

If you're using GnuCash as your accounting system, there are at least two ways to record this transaction:

1. You can bring up the **Transfer Funds** entry screen (and there are at least 3 ways to do that in GnuCash, including clicking on the **Transfer** icon in the icon bar).  Fill in the relevant fields in this entry screen (some fields are optional) and at the absolute minimum these will include the *Amount*, *Date*, *Transfer From* and *Transfer To* fields.  A description (eg. "Caltex, North Melbourne") and memo (eg. "last fill-up before trip to Ballarat") will help the entry to make more sense when you look at it later on.
2. OR (and I prefer this method) you can select your *Expenses:auto:fuel* account from your main **Accounts** screen in GnuCash.  This will open up the register for the *Expenses:auto:fuel* account in its own tab, allowing you to directly enter your transaction into the account register.  Since you're working in the *Expenses:auto:fuel* tab, GnuCash will automatically create a transaction split with that account pre-selected when you create a new transaction.  Fill in that line, then tab down to the next blank split line in the transaction where you can select *Assets:Current Assets:Cash* as the account to be credited.

The *next time* you need to enter a similar transaction in your *Expenses:auto:fuel* register, just start typing the same transaction description in a new blank transaction line, and GnuCash will automatically fill in similar details for the rest of the transaction.  You can either accept the suggested details, or update them to the actual transaction details.

Comment: Thank you for that.  And the 'transaction splits' thing.  I could use that.  I'll look for it. :)